# Variant of stCON

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Consider the following variation on stCON desicion problem:

> Given a directed graph G, decide whether for every two different vertices $s$ and $t$, there is a directed path between $s$ and $t$.

Intuitively, it seems like this problem is indentical to the clique desicion problem, for a clique of size $n$. But does it also belong to NL?

Comment: Your problem asks whether the graph is strongly connected. There’s a classical linear time algorithm for finding SCCs, based on DFS.

Comment: Oh, I got it. But all DFS-based algorithms require polynomial space, aren't they? So this problem doesn't belong to NL?

Comment: We know that NL=coNL.

Comment: What do you mean by "directed path between $s$ and $t$"? Is it necessarily a path *from* $s$ *to* $t$?

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes that you want to check whether for every two vertices $s \neq t$ there is a directed path from $s$ to $t$. If this is the case, we say that the graph is *strongly connected*.

The idea is to use [NL=coNL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immerman%E2%80%93Szelepcs%C3%A9nyi_theorem). In order to check that a directed graph is *not* strongly connected, we guess two vertices $s$ and $t$, and nondeterministically verify (using the algorithm underlying NL=coNL) that $t$ is not reachable from $s$. This shows that your problem is in coNL. Since NL=coNL, it is also in NL.

In fact, your problem is NL-complete, by a simple reduction from stCON; see [notes](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/gs019/asgn/hw6.sol.pdf) of Matulef.